# HTTP 01 chalenge failed using lets-encrypt

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, apache, lets-encrypt, certbot

**I am using ubuntu ec2 apache server hosting nodejs webapp**
and I am trying to use Lets-encrypt to get SSL certificate for my domain drugfair.org
the problem is when I applying sudo certbot --apache
get HTTP 01 challenge fail

```
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain drugfair.org
Challenge failed for domain www.drugfair.org
http-01 challenge for drugfair.org
http-01 challenge for www.drugfair.org
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: drugfair.org
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://drugfair.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/9hPXdeQ4ymWoNAoMtG0ewLzdQxljPMTuDUrTVBJWM7E
   [18.***.*.**]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta
   charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>ReferenceError:
   /var/www"

   Domain: www.drugfair.org
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.drugfair.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/AYVcrbDpcp3ubI0P-pXp0wx_McMlGiopZOzJzhAqyQw
   [18.***.*.**]: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<meta
   charset=\"utf-8\">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>ReferenceError:
   /var/www"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

but when I try to access my website from browser through

http://drugfair.org or through `18.***.*.**:3100/`

it is accessible without reference errors
but when I try to access my website from inside ec2 using this command

`curl http://18.***.**.*:3100`

gives me reference error

Comment: When you again try with new ssl cert creation. Check that your DNS is resolved to correct IP address to all locations https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.drugfair.org .

Comment: Your IP(18.189.6.19) is still visible to everyone.  If you truly want to mask your server IP try using cloudflare or any other proxy.